# Error in Find function in vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, compilation, iteration, std

In this function, I search for the pair.first in the vector cache. The vector is :

```
vector<pair<double,unsigned int> > cache;
```

The custom function I have used for the find function is :

```
struct comp
{
    comp(double const& s) : _s(s) { }

    bool operator () (pair<double, unsigned int> const& p)
    {
        return (p.first == _s);
    }

    double _s;
};
```

I call the find function as :

```
it = find(cache.begin(),cache.end(),comp(value));
```

On compilation, I get a lot of errors. The first few lines are :

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/algorithm:63:0,
>                    from my_class.hpp:5,
>                    from main.cpp:5:
>       /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘*RandomAccessIterator std::*_find(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >, _Tp = MyCode::MyClass::comp]’:
>       /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4326:45:   instantiated from ‘_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >, _Tp = MyCode::MyClass::comp]’
>   my_class.hpp:76:53:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:162:4: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘_*first.*_gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = std::pair*, _Container = std::vector >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = std::pair& == __val’

How can I solve this error ?

Comment: You unfortunately missed the part of the error that is actually the error, rather than some extra information about the error.

Comment: It's still not there. It's probably the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a predicate, not a value, so you need `find_if()`, not `find()`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your call should be using [***`std::find_if`***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), instead of `std::find`.

```
 it = find_if(cache.begin(),cache.end(),comp(value));
 if ( it != cache.end() )
 {


 }
```

Comment: Hah! Beat you by 8 seconds :-)